# Storing huge DataTable in ASP.NET Application variable

Tags: asp.net

Certain SharePoint lists which are frequently accessed by our code are stored in Application variable in the form of DataTable to reduce the number of round trips to the database. This is working fine in most of the scenarios. However, this doesn’t work when the size of the of DataTable is huge, i.e. in the range of 10-12 columns and no. of rows is above 150 000. How do  I get this working?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: How do I get this working? :)

Comment: You will need to give us more context. Why does the large data table fail? What is wrong with round trips to the database?

Comment: Did you consider about having a paging mechanism? Usually as I see a user can't practically interact with this much of records. So consider about bringing what's needed to the client side rather than bringing everything.

Answer (score 0):

IIS could recycle the application if it starts running low on memory. In general you should avoid storing such large datasets in memory. I would recommend you using an out-of-process cache. Checkout [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx). And [here's a guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx) that Scott Hanselman wrote about setting it up. There are also other cache providers such as [memcached](http://memcached.org/) for example.